# Is the copy constructor or the move constructor called when assigning a function return value to a variable?

Tags: c++

I have determined that the return value of func_test is a right value using the overload function. For this line `test a=func_test();`,Why does this line of code call the copy constructor when I don't have a move constructor defined? The move constructor is called when I have defined the move constructor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    int b;
    int* p;
    test() :b(1) {
        p = new int(2);
    }
    ~test()
    {
        delete p;
        cout << this << "delete" << endl;
    }
    test(const test & a)
    {
        b = a.b;
        int tmp = *a.p;
        p = new int(tmp);
        cout << "copy constructor " << endl;
    }
    //test(const test&& d)
    //{
    //  cout << "move constructor" << endl;
    //  p = d.p;
    //  b = d.b;
    //}
};

test func_test()
{
    test a;
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    test a=func_test();
}
```

Comment: moving something that cannot be moved is a copy

Comment: Note that `test a=func_test();` isn't actually assignment, it's [copy *initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). It will copy-initialize `a`, using it's copy-constructor unless the copying is elided.

Comment: Neither, C++ will use copy elission (from C++11 onward). It is more like the object is created by the caller and then initialized by the function. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: Thanks, I should check out the documentation on that.